# SQL Query for select from all column with same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

I have multiple column with same name from multiple table,
`table_1` has column `X`, `table_2` has column `x` and more.
How to select query for `X` column from all table without union. If use union, i must write every table name on query statement, i don't do this. I want do like :

`Select X from (All table with containing X) where X value (not X name) = 'ABC'`.

I use Microsoft SQL.
Is it possible ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using dynamic SQL and build the query this way:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = N''
declare @columnname as nvarchar(100) = N'X'
declare @columnvalue as nvarchar(100) = N'ABC'

select @sql = @sql + N' UNION ALL SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' FROM '
    + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
    + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    + N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' = ''' + @columnvalue +  ''''
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where c.name = @columnname

set @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, N'')

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following it will be useful to you.

```
   Select a.x,b.x
   from table_name a,table_name1 b
   where a.x = b.x
   and a.x = 'ABC';
```

Comment: how if I have hundreds table, i must write every table, any other way ? thanks